# Search for word in a phrase and return match

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, textjoin

I need to build a formula that:

If in column X, has the values ​​of column B (regardless of position), returns the values ​​of A

| Column A |
| --- |
| Amoxicilina |
| Azitromicina |
| Cetoconazol |

| Column B |
| --- |
| Amoxicilina |
| Esomeprazol + Claritromicina + Amoxicilina |
| Amoxicilina + Clavulanato de potássio |
| Azitromicina |
| Cetoconazol |
| Betametasona + Sulfato de Neomicina + Cetoconazol |
| Cetoconazol + Betametasona |

**the result I want is like this:**

| Column B | Column A |
| --- | --- |
| Amoxicilina | Amoxicilina |
| Esomeprazol + Claritromicina + Amoxicilina | Amoxicilina |
| Amoxicilina + Clavulanato de potássio | Amoxicilina |
| Azitromicina | Azitromicina |
| Cetoconazol | Cetoconazol |
| Betametasona + Sulfato de Neomicina + Cetoconazol | Cetoconazol |
| Cetoconazol + Betametasona | Cetoconazol |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(B1:B, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, A1:A))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I used this method (though I am a little unclear of your exact requirement - is it the corresponding column A, or if the thing is contained, return it if it's in column A as well?):

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(C2,"(?i)"&B2),A2,"No Match")
```

The "?i" in the regular expression is to make it case insensitive when searching as shown in the last line.

[image: example]